# What insect is this? Looks like a spider but with six legs and long antennae

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've been spotting some of these insects in my house lately, they look like spiders but it seems like they have six legs and antennae instead of eight legs.
Can someone tell me what insect is this? Is it dangerous? I don't mind having them in my house but if they're dangerous I might have to do something.

A photo of the insect: 
[image: The Insect]

Their body seems to be relatively flat when you look at it from a side, the location is Costa Rica, we are in the wet season (no winter,summer,etc. here) but I'm almost sure I've seen them during the dry season as well, also, the insect's body size (ignoring legs) is similar to a thumb. In case that helps to indentify it.

Comment: In general, it looks like it could be a cricket of some type.  They typically have long antennae.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include an estimate of the size (e.g. around 5 cm long) — thumbs are highly variable and it isn't clear which part(s) of a thumb you might mean anyway! Also, could you try to get clearer pictures and, if possible, include one from the side and another from the front? Thanks! 

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112103/what-kind-of-insect-is-this-it-looks-like-a-huge-spider-with-one-long-antenna-a

Comment: I am think that I have narrowed it down to either [Amblypygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi) (i.e., whips spiders, tailless whip scorpions), or [Solifugae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae) (i.e., camel spiders, wind scorpions, sun spiders). The thing is, in part due to the quality of the photo, I find both clues for and against each option. Long thin antenna-like appendages suggest Amblypygi, but the pedipalps aren't quite right. If it weren't for the think anterior legs, I would say it's a Solifugae. There's also the unidentified appendage that cast shadows don't explain.

Comment: [My perspective, annotated photo](https://imgur.com/a/MgPpX4q)
Rights belong to the initial poster/creator of this post.

Answer (score 3):

This creature is an [amblypygid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi) (aka, whip spider, or tailless whip scorpion). Amblypygids are arachnids, but not spiders, and they are not venomous. Like other arachnids, they have eight legs, however the anterior legs have been modified into very long antennae-like limbs used to feel for prey. Anterior to the antennae-legs are the [pedipalps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedipalp), which have been modified to be long and spiny, used for capturing prey.