# What kind of insect is this? It looks like a huge spider with one long antenna and six legs

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology

[image: an unidentified spider(?) taken at night in Nigeria in May, during rainy season]

It looks like a huge spider but with six legs and has one very long antenna. It also looks like it has claws. Please I would like to know what sort of insect it is. So I would know measures to take if it is dangerous.

Details:

This picture was taken in Nigeria at night. It's raining season here too.

Comment: Similar critter: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93794/what-insect-is-this-looks-like-a-spider-but-with-six-legs-and-long-antennae

Answer (score 6):

While not completely sure, it definitely looks like an Arachnid. Upon further research, I have narrowed it down to either [Amblypygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi) (i.e., whips spiders, tailless whip scorpions), or [Solifugae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae) (i.e., camel spiders, wind scorpions, sun spiders). Using whatever perceptional abilities I have, I have made the educated guess that the appearance of the arthropod you posted most closely resembles that of [Amblypygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi).

The "antenna" is part of the anterior legs (first pair), and not an actual antenna. The other leg of the pair is missing. The appendages in the front that are long and folded are not legs, but pedipalps.

Comment: this is a whip scorpion, family Phrynichidae

Comment: @JimN So, are we in agreement on what this is? The family of Phrynichidae are in the order of [Amblypygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrynichidae). But, Phrynichidae are not "whip scorpions", unless you meant ["tailless whip scorpions" (whip spiders)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi). Whip scorpions are in the order of [Uropygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropygi).

Comment: I'm sorry, I did mean 'whip spider' ! Let's put the common names aside. I agree with order Amblypygi, Family Phrynichidae. This paper mentions two species of the Damon genus in Nigeria: D. johnstonii and D. medius, and many other species in neighbouring countries, but other genera exist as well

Comment: Hm, my previous comment didn't include the paper URL? : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1439609205000425